# JSP: how to include a page with get parameters?

Tags: java, jsp

I need to include a page from an external application in one of my pages.
Now this page expects a get parameter.
So the url would be something like /x/y?z=123.

I was thinking:

```
<jsp:include page="/x/y?z=${zParam}"/>
```

But that doesn't seem to do the trick?
Any advice?

Comment: solved it, and since I can't answer my own question: c:import does the trick.

Comment: sorry, didn't see your comment and added an answer. Anyway, I'm leaving it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try JSTL's `<c:import url="..">`